# GMap shows on page inspect

Tags: 7, google-maps

I am using [GMap Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) (in Drupal 7). Map does not show on page load, but when I inspect the web page, map shows up.
I tried reinstalling module but in vain.
Map shows in GMap Configuration, but on node page it shows only if user inspects page. I have made no change in default GMap code

If anyone has solution to this issue, please share
A bundle of Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to trigger resize when the map is shown.

Try this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
      $('#mymodal').on('shown', function () { 
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');  
      });   
    });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @pallavi-sugandhi for your response. Issue still remains. I think you are reffering my issue with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133318/google-maps-api-works-with-browser-inspect-element

Actually in my case there is no problem with position or size of GMap field.

Comment: Did you get any error in console?

Comment: Nope @pallavi
There isn't any error

Comment: Ok. Have you tried by disabling  'Aggregate JavaScript files' after going to
Configuration --> Development --> Performance page.

Comment: Yes disabled that but no progress.
I dont know why it shows up when I inspect page.

Comment: Actually I have the same issue, but when I added that event then its work fine for me.